# Best way to import data into Cassandra Cluster in c#

Tags: c#, cassandra, batch-processing

I have billions of rows of data in sql server. We are now switching to Cassandra as data warehouse to perform analytics work. SQL server will act as OLTP & Cassandra as OLAP. Data import into cassandra is performed through datastax c# driver. I have been trying out various ways to insert into cassandra through datastax c# driver. What could be the best way to insert massive amount of data?
I have created various PCO (Plain cassandra object) which are mapper to Cassandra Column family. Column family has more than 30 columns.

```
[Table("CF_Data")]
internal class CF_Data
{
    [PartitionKey]
    public Guid Date{ get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset Name { get; set; }
    .................
}
```

First Approach :
I am creating instances of above class & binding it to batch statement. Finally executing batch of per 1000 rows.

```
 var batch  =session.CreateBatch();;
        foreach (cf_Data val in lsData)
        {
            try
            {
                if (((count) % 1000) == 1)
                {
                   batch = session.CreateBatch();
                }
                batch.Append(table.Insert(val)); 
                if (count % 1000 == 0)
                {
                    batch.Execute();   
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
            count++;
        }
```

Second Approach: 
 Insert data through Mapper per row.

```
        try
        {
            IMapper mapper = new Mapper(session);
            foreach (CF_Data val in listData)
            {
                try
                {
                    mapper.Insert(val);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    //throw;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
```

I have also inserted data through PreparedStatement with BatchStatement by binding each properties of CF_Data instance but how could i bind instance of CF_Data (which is one row to be inserted) to PreparedStatement.

```
PreparedStatement ps = session.Prepare(@"INSERT INTO CF_Data
                (
                    Date,
                    Name, ....
                ) " +
                "VALUES (now(),?, ?, ?, ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
```

What could be the best network topology (replication_factor,snitch,..etc) to have best performance with enough copies of data to avoid single point of failure? Right now i have using simplestrategy & replication_factor of 3. How read could be lightening fast as stated by Cassandra team?

Comment: You have too many open questions and contradicting requirements. The problem is that you "can't always get what you want". You need to understand requirements very clearly in order to get a meaningful answer to your question. I'd suggest reading about CAP theorem, that says out of 3 things you can get a balance of 2. BTW Cassandra batching is likely to *slow* your inserts.

Comment: My question is how to get good read & write performance in Cassandra.

Comment: There is no answer to your question. You can get 2 from: good reads, good writes, fault tolerance. It's not a binary choice but a gradient. If you improve your fault tolerance, you likely to degrade writes. When you improve reads you likely to degrade writes. There will be posts saying what to consider and how to optimise for different things (google for this). The lesson that I have learned with Cassandra is that one won't get all the benefits of the SQL databases, like changing query on a fly or using batches to improve import speed, but there will be other ways to achieve the same.

Comment: The best tool for these scenarios is the Cassandra bulk loader: http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/tools/toolsBulkloader_t.html

Comment: I know nothing about Cassandra, but just looking at your batch code above, the last batch of objects (count <1000) will be dropped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd better not using Insert(***) to perform massive data migration, cassandra provide "Copy  ** from **" to import data from csv which may cause timeout for more than 6 M data record, and the better way is @jorgebg said is the sstableloader to load the massive data which will certainly meet your need.

Comment: Is it possible to copy data from c# to Cassandra using sstableloader?

Comment: I think you could do that, here is a reference for java implementation :http://planetcassandra.org/blog/using-the-cassandra-bulk-loader-updated/

Comment: Isn't the `COPY` something only available in the `cqlsh` command line tool?

Comment: @AlexisWilke Yes, the COPY is the command provided by cqlsh, you need to  type 'cqlsh ***'  to enter the session and use the command.

Comment: Yeah and it looks like the OP was asking about a C# solution... I guess you can always run a `system()` call though.